# Show tag popup when hovering tags in Watched or Ignored sections

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags, tag-watching

When I hover a tag in the Watched Tags section, it only shows a tooltip "show questions tagged '[tag name]'":

[image: generic tooltip for watched tags]

However, it will be more useful to have the full tag popup appear there, same as hovering the tag elsewhere:

[image: full tag popup]

Can this please be done? This way I can see info about my Watched Tags without having to visit each of them.

Comment: It's not about getting to the questions, it's already linked, it's about viewing extra info for the tags.

Comment: Presumably you already know what that tag is about if you watch/ignore it :)

Comment: @Glorfindel maybe I watch it only due to its [funny name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorn-meta-zoo)... ;-)